# Fraction to decimals

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $x=0.\overline{456}$ then of course:

$1000 x=456.\overline{456}=456+x$, and therefore:

$x=\frac{456}{999}$

**Question:** how to reverse the above reasoning, **starting** with $x=\frac{456}{999}$?

Of course you can easily get at $1000 x=456+x$ but then how does one proceed to get $x=0.\overline{456}$?

Comment: $$\implies x=0.456+x/1000$$ Then apply fixed-point iteration to get $x=0.456456456456\dots$

Comment: @SimpleArt Can you show me how that is done?

Comment: Repeated substitutions.  Substitute what I had above for the $x$ on the right to get $x=0.456+(0.456+x/1000)/1000=0.456456+x/10^6$, and do that again, and again, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x = \frac {456}{999}$

$999x = 456$

$999x(1.\overline{001}) = 456(1.\overline{001})$

$999.\overline{999}x = 456.{\overline{456}}$

$1000x  = 456.{\overline{456}}$

$x = .{\overline{456}}$

Answer (score 1):

You can show $$\frac{1}{999}=0.001001001\cdots$$ as follows :

$$\frac{1}{999}=\frac{0.001}{0.999}=\frac{0.001}{1-0.001}=0.001+0.000001+\cdots$$

The rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Put $\ n = 10^3\ $ in $\ \dfrac{1}{n-1}\, =\, \dfrac{1}{n}\ \dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}n}\, =\, \dfrac{1}n \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{n} + \dfrac{1}{n^2}+\, \cdots\right)$